# Python date of birth

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, func

Hi I just started to learn python from scratch and stumbled upon this recently

```
birth_year = input('Birth Year: ')
age = 2022 - float(birth_year)
print(age)
```

In the above lines of code used to determine the age of a person if I replace float with bool(just for experimenting) it returns the value 2021 no matter what the inputted birth year is. Can someone please explain why is it doing so?

Comment: Try to break it down into pieces, print out just `bool(birth_year)` to see what happens?

Comment: And then `int(bool(birth_year))`

Comment: Thank you got it! I also have a follow up doubt if u dont mind?....what if I define something other than 'birth_year' in the first line and then without making any changes to the code other than that, run it? will it show 2022 as 'birth_year' is not defined and hence will be treated as false?

Comment: It won't run because Python will tell you you're referring to a variable, birth_year, that it doesn't know anything about in line 2. Try it! It won't break anything, it just will give you an error message.

Comment: sometimes u need to break your code into pieces and see what they are doing, you will get your answer if you print(int(bool(birth_year)))

Comment: got it! thnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

well what are you even expecting bool only has two values 0 or 1.
when you pass some value to 'birth_year' the bool value becomes 1 cause in bool anything except 0 returns 1.
I hope you are following me, and in the end it's like this, (2022-1)=2021

Answer (score 0):

True evaluates to 1 in python. When you call bool() on an integer that does not equal 0, you will get True. You are basically subtracting 1 from 2022 here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a bool can have only two values: 1 (true) or 0 (false) Anything that isn't zero is considered to be true. So when you say 2022 - bool(birth_year), you're really saying 2022 - 1, which will equal 2021.